# How can I read a component property from an other component with Angular 14

Tags: angular

I just want to read a string property from an other component. If I search I find solutions about *ngIf/ngFor, but in my case I don't show this property in html file. I just want to read the string property from an other component.

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

// THIS PROPERTY I WANT TO READ FROM AN OTHER COMPONENT
userRefid!: string;

  onSubmit(): void {
    const { email, password } = this.form;
    this.authService.login(email, password).subscribe({
      next: data => {
        this.storageService.saveUser(data);
        this.isLoginFailed = false;
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
        this.roles = this.storageService.getUser().roles;

        // HERE I GET THE VALUE FROM DB
        this.userRefid = this.storageService.getUser().refid; 
        this.reloadPage();
      },
      error: err => {
        this.errorMessage = err.error.message;
        this.isLoginFailed = true;
      }
    });
  }
}

export class ModeratorComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChildren(LoginComponent) loginComponent!: LoginComponent;
  currentUserRefid: any;


  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.currentUserRefid = this.loginComponent.userRefid;
  }

}
```

In the function ngAfterViewInit the this.loginComponent gets always: ERROR TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'userRefid')
the loginComponent is always undefined

I want to know what I have to use, ViewChild/ViewChildren or maybe something else to exchange properties from one component to an other.

Answer (score 0):

Given the little piece of code you provided, it's probably because your component is not displayed.

Check that the `LoginComponent` is NOT in a tag that contains a `*ngIf`.

Or better, provide the HTML for the parent component !

Comment: Also : the error is at this line `this.userRefid = this.storageService.getUser()`, it is NOT when you try to access the value. So it's again, probably because you have your loginComponent inside an if statement !

Comment: There is nothing in my html code. That is just the point. I want to access properties between components without html ngIf and things like that. Is it not possible to exchange properties between components?

Comment: Let me be the judge of that. Clearly, your login component get unmounted from the view, let it be routing, ngif, or something else.